# Shimano clipless pedals and cleats

Tags: shimano, clipless

My pedals call for ph51 cleats and that's what I put on my shoes but I can't hardly get unclipped and I've got the pedal adjustment backed all the way out counter clockways and it's really hard to get unclipped. I have both knees replaced and I shouldn't torque my knees real hard. And this is a little scary when I try to come to a stop and can't get out of my pedals.

Comment: Are these new cleats you have installed? I am inferring that but just want to be clear. Details do matter.

Comment: Do your pedals have a "spring tension" adjustment screw?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

What pedals, genuine Shimano or other 'SPD compatible' brand. I have a set of pedals that sound the same - they are very hard (bordering on dangerous) to unclip with one Shimano cleat and work perfectly with the other (SH51, SH56, can't remember which one works), could be worth trying SH56. With knee replacement, you may prefer the multi release SH56 anyway.

The other thing to check is the shoe is clear of the pedal. With MTB shoes, it is not unknown to have to trim the tread to get them to work with a particular pedal.

Comment: I prefer to file down bits of pedal, as the ones that interfere tend to be those with a cage as well (M424, for example) and pedals are cheaper and longer lasting than shoes.